# Differential-linear attack on DES

Tags: des, differential-analysis, linear-cryptanalysis

Is there any known differential-linear attack on full round DES? I couldn't found any and couldn't work on this due to time restriction.

Comment: It's unclear what the question means by "Differential-linear attack". Is it asked if the [differential cryptanalysis](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~biham/Reports/differential-cryptanalysis-of-the-data-encryption-standard-biham-shamir-authors-latex-version.pdf#page=14) and [linear cryptanalysis](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48658-5_1) of DES work on full DES with all rounds? What's left of the question after reading the summary of the linked material?

Comment: the OP should clarify but it may be related to his other recent question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/86160/enhancing-linear-differential-cryptanalysis-biham-et-al-diff-lin-extension

Answer (score 1):

For [this particular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-linear_attack) type of attack, [the best](http://www.cs.haifa.ac.il/%7Eorrd/crypt/diff-lin.pdf) it can do is attack 10 rounds of DES, with 2^50 time complexity and 2^20 plaintexts.

Comment: I was referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-linear_attack) attack, as @Modal Nest mentioned. Thanks for the answer, appreciated ^^